# regex negative lookbehind - pcre

Tags: regex, pcre, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to write a rule to match on a top level domain followed by five digits.  My problem arises because my existing pcre is matching on what I have described but much later in the URL then when I want it to.  I want it to match on the first occurence of a TLD, not anywhere else. The easy way to check for this is to match on the TLD when it has not bee preceeded at some point by the "/" character.  I tried using negative-lookbehind but that doesn't work because that only looks back one single character.

**e.g.: How it is currently working**

```
domain.net/stuff/stuff=www.google.com/12345
```

matches .com/12345 even though I do not want this match because it is not the first TLD in the URL

**e.g.: How I want it to work**

```
domain.net/12345/stuff=www.google.com/12345
```

matches on .net/12345 and ignores the later match on .com/12345

My current expression

```
(\.[a-z]{2,4})/\d{5}
```

EDIT: rewrote it so perhaps the problem is clearer in case anyone in the future has this same issue.

Comment: I don’t understand what exactly you want to match and what not. Please give a more concise example.

Comment: I have no idea what should (and should not) match based on your description. Please [edit] your post and provide a few matches AND a few non-matches, so we have some indication of what it is you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have rewritten it, hopefully that makes it clearer for any future user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close :)

You just need to be sure that before matching what you're looking for (i.e: `(\.[a-z]{2,4})/\d{5}`), you haven't met any `/` since the beginning of the line.

I would suggest you to simply preppend `^[^\/]*\.` before your current regex.
Thus, the resulting regex would be:

```
^[^\/]*\.([a-z]{2,4})/\d{5}
```

---

How does it work?

- `^` asserts that this is the beginning of the tested String
- `[^\/]*` accepts any sequence of characters that doesn't contain `/`
- `\.([a-z]{2,4})/\d{5}` is the pattern you want to match (a `.` followed by 2 to 4 lowercase characters, then a `/` and at least 5 digits).

Here is a [permalink to a working example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qO0rC2).
Cheers!

Comment: Man, I was really close then because I did have [^/] before my pcre and it wasn't working.  Thank  you so much for the explanation break down line by line.  This really helps me understand it better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
'|^(\w+://)?([\w-]+\.)+\w+/\d{5}|'
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/